# mariadb optimisation of primary key not working

Tags: mysql, mariadb

If you use a count on a non-null-column, on one table, without any where-parts, the optimaizer just return the number of rows in that table.

If you ask for a DISTINCT count on a UNIQE non-null-column, like the PRIMARY KEY, the answers should be the same, but this time mariadb do the calculations insted.

And if you have left join on other tables, and still no where-parts, the results should still be the number of rows in that table.

Is there a reason for mariadb not using thous optimizations? Is there case when the DISTINCT count of an unfiltered primary key, could give any other result then the number of rows in that tabel?

case:

```
CREATE TABLE products (
    our_article_id varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
    ...,
    PRIMARY KEY(our_article_id)
);

CREATE TABLE product_article_id (
    article_id varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
    our_article_id varchar(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY(article_id),
    INDEX(our_article_id)
);
```

Count queries, 1st, basic count

```
DESCRIBE SELECT COUNT(our_article_id) FROM products;         
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+------------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                        |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+------------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | NULL  | NULL | NULL          | NULL | NULL    | NULL | NULL | Select tables optimized away |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+------------------------------+
```

2nd DISTINCT on primary key

```
DESCRIBE SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT our_article_id) FROM products;
+------+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table    | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+------+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | products | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 152     | NULL | 225089 | Using index |
+------+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
```

3th, DISTINCT on PRIMARY KEY, and a LEFT JOIN without WHERE-parts

```
DESCRIBE SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT our_article_id) FROM products LEFT JOIN product_article_id USING (our_article_id);
+------+-------------+--------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------+--------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table              | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref                              | rows   | Extra       |
+------+-------------+--------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------+--------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | products           | index | NULL          | PRIMARY | 152     | NULL                             | 225089 | Using index |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | product_article_id | ref   | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 152     | testseek.products.our_article_id |  12579 | Using index |
+------+-------------+--------------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+----------------------------------+--------+-------------+
```

Comment: You are not setting an engine in the table definition. Are you using InnoDB or MyISAM?

Comment: my default config have: ENGINE=InnoDB

Comment: In which case would you be in a situation where you need DISTINCT count on a non-null unique column? How would that result differ from a regular count on that column?

Comment: I think @PugganSe is asking not how to make his query faster, but why the MariaDB / MySQL query planner doesn't recognize `COUNT(DISTINCT pk)` as always having the same result as `COUNT(*)`. What's the design reason for that? Great question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Is there a reason for mariadb not using thous optimizations?" -- There are a zillion missing optimizations in MySQL/MariaDB; that's missing.  Let's look at the history.

MySQL started about 2 decades ago as a lean and mean database engine.  It focused on features that most people needed, while minimizing the overhead.  This meant that a lot of rare optimizations were not in the early releases, and only get added over time if they seem important enough.

Take the `PRIMARY KEY`, for example.  It is defined as UNIQUE.  It is BTree organized.  And, with InnoDB, it is also defined as Clustered.  Other vendors allow various combinations clustering, non-BTree indexing, etc.  MySQL decided that the limitations were "good enough" for "most" people.

Over the years, the 'worst' omissions have been gradually fixed.  Transactions is probably the biggest and most important.  It arrived in 2001(?), and MyISAM is being removed this year (2016) with the advent of 8.0.

4.1 (2002?) saw subqueries.  Before that, creating a tmp table was "good enough".  Now (8.0) subqueries are being one-upped by CTEs, which covers a few things that neither tmp tables nor subqueries can do efficiently.

There have been a huge number of optimizations put into MySQL 5.6 and 5.7 and MariaDB 10.x; you probably have not used more than a couple of them.  The product is into "diminishing returns".  It would damage its "lean and mean" heritage if it slowed down the optimizer to check for the next thousand extremely rare optimizations.

Meanwhile, guys like me spend a lot of time saying "MySQL/MariaDB doesn't have that; here's the workaround".  It's the shorter `COUNT(*)` in your case.  Since there is a clean workaround, it may be another decade before your suggestions are implemented.  It is OK to file a bug report with bugs.mysql.com or mariadb.com to suggest the optimizations.

Another, almost never needed case, is `INDEX(a ASC, b DESC)` as a way of optimizing `ORDER BY a ASC, b DESC`.  That is coming with 8.0.  But I doubt if more than one query in 5,000 really needs it.  (I have seen a lot of queries.)  I suggest that its rarity is why it took two decades to implement it.  The lack of a clean workaround is why it did not take another decade.